# Sign a PDF using C# and a free 3rd party component?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

is there a reliable way to sign PDFs from a commercial ASP.NET (C#) application? The component should be free to use. I saw iText, but its not free for commercial use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use ITextSharp as long as you use version 4.1.6 or older. Unfortunately, they have removed it from sourceforge but you can download it (with a sample application) at https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx.

I have been using it for filling pdf forms and it works like a charm :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try PDF Sharp : http://www.pdfsharp.net/.